# Specific type of box around equation

Tags: math-mode, mathdesign, fancybox, colorbox

When I write notes by hand, if I want to box an equation, I usually do it in the following way. I find the lowest (highest) point of the equation, I go a little bit higher (lower) and take a line, cutting it a little before and after the aforementioned point. If there are more than one extrema of equal height I do it for all of them (pic related). [image]

Is there any way to do this in LaTeX? (for example with TikZ I guess)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Short answer: Package [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) provides boxes like `\tcbhighmath` or `\tcbboxmath` for such thing. And please always add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you already have.

Comment: @Schweinebacke [tcolorbox's](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) boxes you suggested do not do what I asked for. You probably didn't even read the question.  I knew about [tcolorbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) but I also knew it wasn't satisfying. And for MWE; wouldn't it be the same (if not worse, for cluttering the question) to provide a MWE with a simple colorbox around an equation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDITED to turn it into a macro.  Took Dai's suggestion to add a `\strut`, to account for squat equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine}
\newcommand\redbox[1]{%
  \fboxsep=-2pt
  \def\tmp{\displaystyle\strut #1}
  \def\shadow{\makebox[.4pt]{$\tmp$}}
  \stackengine{0pt}{%
    \stackengine{0pt}{%
      \textcolor{red}{\fbox{~~$\phantom{\tmp}$~~}}%
    }{\color{white}\shadow\shadow\shadow\shadow\shadow\shadow\shadow%
      \shadow\shadow\shadow\shadow}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}%
  }{$\tmp$}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}
}
\begin{document}
\[
\redbox{z(t) = \int D\vec m e^{-\int d^\alpha x
 \Phi[...]}}
\]
\[
\redbox{y = \int_0^\tau e^t dt}
\]
\[
\redbox{x = y + z}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: renamed the macro to `radbox` in my file. Thanks :D

Comment: Possibly using `\fbox{~~$\phantom{\strut\tmp}$~~}` would be desirable (e.g. `\redbox{x=y+z}` without the `\strut` is boxed rather tighter than likely to be preferable).